# Match rows in a panda dataframe based on values in two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with about half a million rows.
The columns are `['in','out']`.
I need to find whether for each row `i` there is another row `j` that matches it. The condition for the match is:

```
df.in[i] == df.out[j]  and df.out[i] == df.in[j]
```

I've implemented it as a for loop:

```py
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    match_row = (d.out == row['in']) & (df.in == row['out'])
    if len(df[match_row].value) > 0:
        #do something
```

As [Nick Becker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6066528/nick-becker) suggested, here is a small sample data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'in':[10,20,30,40,50,60], 'out':[20,10,40,30,70,80]})
```

```
    in  out
0   10  20
1   20  10
2   30  40
3   40  30
4   50  70
5   60  80
```

I need to match row 0 with row 1 and row 2 with row 3.
I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do it without using a for loop.

[UPDATE]
Since there are some suggestions (thank you) on how to solve this problem, I'd like to post here what I expect to get. Here is the code and the output:

```py
matches = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    match_row = (df['out'] == row['in']) & (df['in'] == row['out'])
    if len(df[match_row]) > 0:
        matches.append((i, df[match_row].index[0],row['in'], row['out'] ))
pd.DataFrame(matches, columns = ['row', 'match row', 'in','out'])
    row matching_row    in  out
0   0   1               10  20
1   1   0               20  10
2   2   3               30  40
3   3   2               40  30
```

I can do some clean up to remove duplication, but this is basically what I'm looking for. Is it an inherently sequential problem and there is nothing I can do about it?

Comment: If you just need to find whether each observation in `in` occurs in`out`, perhaps you can just use `df['in'].isin(df['out'])` to generate the Boolean mask all at once. In general, you should try to avoid looping through dataframes row by row, and also include a small, representative snippet of data with your question.

Comment: I need both, e.g for a pair  (40, 60) I need to find a pair (60,40).

Comment: Along @NickBecker's recommendation, you could do an AND operation on the booleans generated from `df['in'].isin(df['out'])` and `df['out'].isin(df['in'])`. That would give you the boolean mask for your specific requirement.

Comment: @VishakhaLall I can do (df['in'].isin(df['out'])) & (df['out'].isin(df['in'])) for my simple example the output is:   True, True, True, True, False,  False. I know rows 0,1,2, and 3 match, but I don't know whether row 0 matches row 1 or row 2 or row 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge` in `pandas` to join the dataframe to itself. The default is an inner join. Does this help?

```
df.merge(df, left_on=["in", "out"], right_on=["out", "in"], suffixes=('_left', '_right'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following on your simple sample data, isn't this what you are looking for?

```
df['in-in-out'] = df['in'].isin(df['out'])
df['out-in-in'] = df['out'].isin(df['in'])
df['and'] = df['in-in-out'] & df['out-in-in']
df = df.drop(['in-in-out', 'out-in-in'], axis=1)
df = df[df['and']]
df = df.drop(['and'], axis=1)
```

The output is

```
    in  out
0   10  20
1   20  10
2   30  40
3   40  30
```

Of course I have added extra columns and dropped them for clarity so you can see how the dataframe is being modified at each step.